# ssh authorized_keys file location and permissions

Tags: ssh, permissions, openssh, authentication, authorized-keys

I am confused on the permissions that ssh requires when dealing with custom *authorized_keys* files.

For example, assuming that we have a server the following line in file */etc/ssh/sshd_config*:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/authorized_keys
```

It means that theoretically we can access the server with all the keys inserted in those two files, considering that *.ssh/authorized_keys* is a per-user file (meaning that we can log in with user root using the keys in file */etc/ssh/authorized_keys* and */home/root/authorized_keys*).

Now, how can this even work a non-root user for */etc/ssh/authorized_keys*, if when using the default mode `StrictMode yes` does not allow to use the *authorized_keys* file unless the parent folders are with permission 0700 and owned by the user (which is not the case here) and the file is owned by the user and has permission 0600 (that we can assume is the case)?

Ssh won't accept the keys in */etc/ssh/authorized_keys* for a non-root user, since the permission are not correct for that user (the owner of */etc/ssh* is *root*).

Or am I missing something?

Comment: See `safe_path` in `misc.c` and `platform_sys_dir_uid` in `platform-misc.c`; the actual requirement is that the file and dirs (up to either the user's homedir or the root) are unwritable by other than owner and are owned by the desired uid OR ROOT (OR if configured at build time one other uid, which could e.g. be assigned for an sftp server)

Comment: thank you for the answer, I understand now!

Comment: Isn't it *"ssh_config"* (not *"sshd_config"* - without *"d"*)?

Answer (score 2):

@dave_thompson_085's comment on the question really nails it, so expanding on this as to not leave this question without a formal answer:

In [`misc.c`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/misc.c), function `safe_path()` states, as of 2023-06:

```
/*
 * Check a given path for security. This is defined as all components
 * of the path to the file must be owned by either the owner of
 * of the file or root and no directories must be group or world writable.
 *
 * XXX Should any specific check be done for sym links ?
 *
 * Takes a file name, its stat information (preferably from fstat() to
 * avoid races), the uid of the expected owner, their home directory and an
 * error buffer plus max size as arguments.
 *
 * Returns 0 on success and -1 on failure
 */
int
safe_path(const char *name, struct stat *stp, const char *pw_dir,
    uid_t uid, char *err, size_t errlen)
{
    ...
    if ((!platform_sys_dir_uid(stp->st_uid) && stp->st_uid != uid) ||
        (stp->st_mode & 022) != 0) {
        snprintf(err, errlen, "bad ownership or modes for file %s",
            buf);
        return -1;
    }
    ...
    (similarly to each path component)
}
```

This function is called by `safe_path_fd()` wrapper, and if considering both, their usage regarding `authorized_keys` appears to be in `auth_openfile()` from [`auth2-pubkeyfile.c`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/auth2-pubkeyfile.c):

```
static FILE *
auth_openfile(const char *file, struct passwd *pw, int strict_modes,
    int log_missing, char *file_type)
{
...
    if (strict_modes &&
        safe_path_fd(fileno(f), file, pw, line, sizeof(line)) != 0) {
        fclose(f);
        logit("Authentication refused: %s", line);
        auth_debug_add("Ignored %s: %s", file_type, line);
        return NULL;
    }
...
}
```

Where `strict_modes` comes from [`StrictModes` option in `sshd_config`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html)

In conclusion, answering your question:

> Now, how can this even work a non-root user for /etc/ssh/authorized_keys if [...] does not allow to use [...] unless the parent folders are with permission 0700 and owned by the user [...] and the file is owned by the user and has permission 0600?
> Or am I missing something?

You're misreading the requirements stated in [`sshd documentation`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sshd.8.html#FILES):

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
        Lists the public keys (DSA, ECDSA, Ed25519, RSA) that can
        be used for logging in as this user.  The format of this
        file is described above.  The content of the file is not
        highly sensitive, but the recommended permissions are
        read/write for the user, and not accessible by others.

        If this file, the ~/.ssh directory, or the user's home
        directory are writable by other users, then the file could
        be modified or replaced by unauthorized users.  In this
        case, sshd will not allow it to be used unless the
        StrictModes option has been set to “no”.
```

Note it never *requires* a strict 0600 for the `authorized_keys` file, it merely *recommends* it. And for directories, it only requires each component  *not to be world-(or group-)**writable***, so they can be 0755 just fine. And that's why the code only checks for a `022` *mask*.

And, also looking at the code, `root` is always allowed as the owner, both by `sshd` and by the filesystem, so `authorized_keys` can even be `0000` `---------- root:root` (remember sshd process *runs* as root). This is unfortunately never explicitly said in the manual, but OTOH it also doesn't ever say that the file owner and the user logging in must match (the code does).